# How to sort materilas by date in MODx manager (adminpanel)?

Tags: sorting, date, modx, modx-revolution

My MODx version is Revolution 2.4.2. I'm search for a while time for solutions, but finding only how to sort them in front pages. How can i sort materials in adminpanel (manager) by date?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can make it a lot easier for others to answer your question, if you follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Please make sure to edit your post accordingly, as a lack of quality in a question might result in others not bothering to answer

Answer (score 0):

For rapid quick editing in MODx I use CRUD outside MODx manager in separate folder /crud for example and password protect it with .htaccess. There are many there - for example I use www.phpgrid.org that is paid script but for basics that you need there's free version. There's also for example free www.grocerycrud.com and many others.

Basically you display all MODx resources (MySQL table: modx_site_content) in a nice table where you can quickly sort, filter, edit, add, delete all resources. I have in my table for example id, pagetitle, longtitle, introtext, alias, parent, content, menutitle, description, menuindex, pub_date, template and publishedon columns and hide all other columns but it's up to you how you set it up.

I can share my example code to display it all if you want but if you spend half an hour playing around with phpgrid.org for example then they have good examples and you'll be able to set up rapidly CRUD for any MySQL table. Hope you'll like it.